# Can I force VBA to treat a Variant arg differently when Empty vs Zero?

Tags: vba

Given that a variant that is Empty = 0, am looking to see if anyone has a trick to distinguish between the two, as in the dummy function below

```vb
Function doGetFmt(v As Variant) As String
    dim s as String
    If IsEmpty(v) Then s ="Empty"
    If v=0 s= "zero"
    doGetFmt = s
End Function
```

Comment: `Empty <> 0`, but it can appear to be so in comparisons due to implicit conversions. If you are not happy with the implicit conversions, don't let them happen with strong typing / value checks (that may involve `IsEmpty()` and/or `VarType()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following from GSerg's comment:

```
Dim v As Variant

Debug.Print IsEmpty(v) '>> #true#
Debug.Print v = 0      '>> true

v = 0

Debug.Print IsEmpty(v) '>> #false#
Debug.Print v = 0      '>> true
```

If you  only test for zero if `IsEmpty()` returns false then you're closer to what you want.